# How can I save/store and load back editor window changes?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to use JsonUtility but it's not doing much.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor.Callbacks;
using UnityEditor.IMGUI.Controls;
using UnityEngine;


namespace UnityEditor.TreeViewExamples
{
    class CustomHeightWindow : EditorWindow
    {
        [NonSerialized] bool m_Initialized;
        [SerializeField] TreeViewState m_TreeViewState; // Serialized in the window layout file so it survives assembly reloading
        SearchField m_SearchField;
        static CustomHeightTreeView m_TreeView;
        MyTreeAsset m_MyTreeAsset;
        SimpleTreeView simple_m_TreeView;

        private static int numofconversations = 10;
        private static int oldnumofconversations;

        [MenuItem("TreeView Examples/Custom Row Heights")]
        public static CustomHeightWindow GetWindow()
        {
            var window = GetWindow<CustomHeightWindow>();
            window.titleContent = new GUIContent("Custom Heights");
            window.Focus();
            window.Repaint();

            oldnumofconversations = numofconversations;
            CustomHeightTreeView.numberofactive = 0;

            return window;
        }

        protected void OnEnable()
        {
            var data = EditorPrefs.GetString("CustomHeightWindow", JsonUtility.ToJson(this, false));
            // Then we apply them to this window
            JsonUtility.FromJsonOverwrite(data, this);
        }

        protected void OnDisable()
        {
            // We get the Json data
            var data = JsonUtility.ToJson(this, false);
            // And we save it
            EditorPrefs.SetString("CustomHeightWindow", data);
        }

        [OnOpenAsset]
        public static bool OnOpenAsset(int instanceID, int line)
        {
            var myTreeAsset = EditorUtility.InstanceIDToObject(instanceID) as MyTreeAsset;
            if (myTreeAsset != null)
            {
                var window = GetWindow();
                window.SetTreeAsset(myTreeAsset);
                return true;
            }
            return false; // we did not handle the open
        }

        void SetTreeAsset(MyTreeAsset myTreeAsset)
        {
            m_MyTreeAsset = myTreeAsset;
            m_Initialized = false;
        }

        Rect treeViewRect
        {
            get { return new Rect(20, 70, position.width - 40, position.height - 100); }
        }

        Rect toolbarRect
        {
            get { return new Rect(20f, 10f, position.width - 40f, 20f); }
        }

        Rect bottomToolbarRect
        {
            get { return new Rect(20f, position.height - 18f, position.width - 40f, 16f); }
        }

        void InitIfNeeded()
        {
            if (!m_Initialized)
            {
                // Check if it already exists (deserialized from window layout file or scriptable object)
                if (m_TreeViewState == null)
                    m_TreeViewState = new TreeViewState();

                var treeModel = new TreeModel<MyTreeElement>(GetData());
                m_TreeView = new CustomHeightTreeView(m_TreeViewState, treeModel);
                m_SearchField = new SearchField();
                m_SearchField.downOrUpArrowKeyPressed += m_TreeView.SetFocusAndEnsureSelectedItem;

                m_Initialized = true;
            }
        }

        IList<MyTreeElement> GetData()
        {
            if (m_MyTreeAsset != null && m_MyTreeAsset.treeElements != null && m_MyTreeAsset.treeElements.Count > 0)
                return m_MyTreeAsset.treeElements;

            // generate some test data
            return MyTreeElementGenerator.GenerateRandomTree(numofconversations);
        }

        void OnSelectionChange()
        {
            if (!m_Initialized)
                return;

            var myTreeAsset = Selection.activeObject as MyTreeAsset;
            if (myTreeAsset != null && myTreeAsset != m_MyTreeAsset)
            {
                m_MyTreeAsset = myTreeAsset;
                m_TreeView.treeModel.SetData(GetData());
                m_TreeView.Reload();
            } 
        }

        void OnGUI()
        {
            if(oldnumofconversations != numofconversations)
            {
                m_Initialized = false;
                oldnumofconversations = numofconversations;
            }

            InitIfNeeded();

            SearchBar(toolbarRect);
            DoTreeView(treeViewRect);
            BottomToolBar(bottomToolbarRect);
            DoFields();
            DoTreeView();
        }

        void SearchBar(Rect rect)
        {
            m_TreeView.searchString = m_SearchField.OnGUI(rect, m_TreeView.searchString);
        }

        void DoTreeView(Rect rect)
        {
            m_TreeView.OnGUI(rect);
        }

        void BottomToolBar(Rect rect)
        {
            GUILayout.BeginArea(rect);

            using (new EditorGUILayout.HorizontalScope())
            {
                var style = "miniButton";
                if (GUILayout.Button("Expand All", style))
                {
                    m_TreeView.ExpandAll();
                }

                if (GUILayout.Button("Collapse All", style))
                {
                    m_TreeView.CollapseAll();
                }
            }

            GUILayout.EndArea();
        }

        void DoFields()
        {
            DrawBox(new Rect(20, 35, position.width - 40, 30),"", Color.white);
            numofconversations = EditorGUI.IntField(new Rect(187, 43, 50, 15), numofconversations);
            GUI.Label(new Rect(37, 41, 150, 15), "Number of conversations");

            GUI.Label(new Rect(250, 41, 220, 15), "Number of collapsed conversations");
            EditorGUI.IntField(new Rect(458, 43, 50, 15), CustomHeightTreeView.numberofactive);
        }

        void DrawBox(Rect position, string content, Color color)
        {
            Color oldColor = GUI.color;

            GUI.color = color;
            GUI.Box(position, content);

            GUI.color = oldColor;
        }

        void DoTreeView()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

For some reason when I close and then open back the window it's saving the variable numofconversations but only this variable.
If when the window is open in the editor I'm changing the numofconversations value to 100 next time I will open the window it will be 100.

But I want to also to store for example the variable state :

```
CustomHeightTreeView.numberofactive
```

I set it to 0 but when it's value is changing in the editor it's not saving it.

This is the custom script :

```
using UnityEditor.IMGUI.Controls;
using UnityEngine;


namespace UnityEditor.TreeViewExamples
{
    internal class CustomHeightTreeView : TreeViewWithTreeModel<MyTreeElement>
    {
        public static int numberofactive = 0;
        public static bool isactive = false;

        static class Styles
        {
            public static GUIStyle background = "RL Background";
            public static GUIStyle headerBackground = "RL Header";
        }

        public CustomHeightTreeView(TreeViewState state, TreeModel<MyTreeElement> model)
            : base(state, model)
        {
            // Custom setup
            showBorder = true;
            customFoldoutYOffset = 3f;

            Reload();
        }

        protected override float GetCustomRowHeight (int row, TreeViewItem item)
        {
            var myItem = (TreeViewItem<MyTreeElement>)item;

            if (myItem.data.enabled)
                return 85f;

            return 30f;
        }

        public override void OnGUI (Rect rect)
        {
            // Background
            if (Event.current.type == EventType.Repaint)
                DefaultStyles.backgroundOdd.Draw(rect, false, false, false, false);

            // TreeView
            base.OnGUI (rect);
        }

        protected override void RowGUI (RowGUIArgs args)
        {
            var item = (TreeViewItem<MyTreeElement>) args.item;
            var contentIndent = GetContentIndent (item);
            // Background
            var bgRect = args.rowRect;
            bgRect.x = contentIndent;
            bgRect.width = Mathf.Max (bgRect.width - contentIndent, 155f) - 5f;
            bgRect.yMin += 2f;
            bgRect.yMax -= 2f;

            DrawItemBackground(bgRect);

            if(item.data.enabled == true && isactive == true)
            {
                DrawItemBackgroundColor(bgRect);
            }

            /*if(item.data.enabled == true && isactive == false)
            {
                isactive = true;
                numberofactive++;
                DrawItemBackgroundColor(bgRect);
            }*/

            // Custom label
            var headerRect = bgRect;
            headerRect.xMin += 5f;
            headerRect.xMax -= 10f;
            headerRect.height = Styles.headerBackground.fixedHeight;
            HeaderGUI (headerRect, args.label, item);

            // Controls
            var controlsRect = headerRect;
            controlsRect.xMin += 20f;
            controlsRect.y += headerRect.height;
            if (item.data.enabled)
                ControlsGUI (controlsRect, item);
        }

        void DrawItemBackground (Rect bgRect)
        {
            if (Event.current.type == EventType.Repaint)
            {
                var rect = bgRect;
                rect.height = Styles.headerBackground.fixedHeight;
                Styles.headerBackground.Draw(rect, false, false, false, false);

                rect.y += rect.height;
                rect.height = bgRect.height - rect.height;
                Styles.background.Draw(rect, false, false, false, false);
            }
        }

        void DrawItemBackgroundColor(Rect bgRect)
        {
            if (Event.current.type == EventType.Repaint)
            {
                Color oldColor = GUI.color; 
                GUI.color = new Color32(255, 182, 193,100);

                var rect = bgRect;
                rect.height = Styles.headerBackground.fixedHeight;
                Styles.headerBackground.Draw(rect, false, false, false, false);

                rect.y += rect.height;
                rect.height = bgRect.height - rect.height;
                Styles.background.Draw(rect, false, false, false, false);

                GUI.color = oldColor;
            }
        }

        void HeaderGUI (Rect headerRect, string label, TreeViewItem<MyTreeElement> item)
        {
            headerRect.y += 1f;

            // Do toggle
            Rect toggleRect = headerRect;
            toggleRect.width = 16;
            EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck ();
                item.data.enabled = EditorGUI.Toggle(toggleRect, item.data.enabled); // hide when outside cell rect
            if (EditorGUI.EndChangeCheck())
            {
                RefreshCustomRowHeights();

                if (item.data.enabled == true)
                {
                    isactive = true;
                    numberofactive++;
                }
                else
                {
                    numberofactive--;
                }
            }

            Rect labelRect = headerRect;
            labelRect.xMin += toggleRect.width + 2f;
            GUI.Label (labelRect, label);
        }

        void ControlsGUI(Rect controlsRect, TreeViewItem<MyTreeElement> item)
        {
            var rect = controlsRect;
            rect.y += 3f;
            rect.height = EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight;
            item.data.floatValue1 = EditorGUI.Slider(rect, GUIContent.none, item.data.floatValue1, 0f, 1f);
            rect.y += rect.height + EditorGUIUtility.standardVerticalSpacing;
            item.data.material = (Material)EditorGUI.ObjectField(rect, GUIContent.none, item.data.material, typeof(Material), false);
            rect.y += rect.height + EditorGUIUtility.standardVerticalSpacing;
            item.data.text = GUI.TextField(rect, item.data.text);
        }

        protected override Rect GetRenameRect (Rect rowRect, int row, TreeViewItem item)
        {
            // Match label perfectly
            var renameRect = base.GetRenameRect (rowRect, row, item);
            renameRect.xMin += 25f;
            renameRect.y += 2f;
            return renameRect;
        }

        // Rename
        //--------

        protected override bool CanRename(TreeViewItem item)
        {
            // Only allow rename if we can show the rename overlay with a certain width (label might be clipped by other columns)
            Rect renameRect = GetRenameRect (treeViewRect, 0, item);
            return renameRect.width > 30;
        }

        protected override void RenameEnded(RenameEndedArgs args)
        {
            // Set the backend name and reload the tree to reflect the new model
            if (args.acceptedRename)
            {
                var element = treeModel.Find(args.itemID);
                element.name = args.newName;
                Reload();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this script I'm setting the variable numberofactive according to the number of currently enabled items :

```
void HeaderGUI (Rect headerRect, string label, TreeViewItem<MyTreeElement> item)
        {
            headerRect.y += 1f;

            // Do toggle
            Rect toggleRect = headerRect;
            toggleRect.width = 16;
            EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck ();
                item.data.enabled = EditorGUI.Toggle(toggleRect, item.data.enabled); // hide when outside cell rect
            if (EditorGUI.EndChangeCheck())
            {
                RefreshCustomRowHeights();

                if (item.data.enabled == true)
                {
                    isactive = true;
                    numberofactive++;
                }
                else
                {
                    numberofactive--;
                }
            }

            Rect labelRect = headerRect;
            labelRect.xMin += toggleRect.width + 2f;
            GUI.Label (labelRect, label);
        }
```

When the window is opened in the editor if I toggle and collapse for example 5 items it will update the variable numberofactive to 5 and then if toggle only 3 then to 3. But it's not saving it.

That's one variable it's not saving there are more others.
For example it's not saving also the item.enable states. If item.enable is true or false it's not saving it and not toggling it when opening the window first time.

I know the code is long but the idea is save the editor window states of the variables values and visual gui.